# JsonSyntaxException because of IllegalState of gson

Tags: gson

I have a strange behavior when parsing a json with gson. I use this code:

```
private static Container parseContainer(String containerJson) {

    try {
        //TODO Remove try catch when Bug is done
        return containerJson != null ? new Gson().fromJson(containerJson, Container.class)
                : null;

    } catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
        LOGGER.error("JsonSyntaxException ", e);
        LOGGER.error("Json: " + containerJson);

        //Sleep 3 minutes and try again.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000L * 60 * 3);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            LOGGER.error("Exception", e);
        }

        LOGGER.error("Try again to parse json: " + containerJson);

        Container result = new Gson().fromJson(containerJson, Container.class);

        LOGGER.error("Parsing successful on second try.");

        return result;
    }

}
```

When the method is invoked in my project, it usually works without throwing the exception. But sometimes the exception is thrown and after waiting some time, the parsing works fine.

I haven't figured out when the exception is thrown and when not.

How can the log "Parsing successful on second try" ever be logged?

The Exception is

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
at     com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapt    erFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
```

Comment: Seems like the exception is being thrown on the fromJson call right before the "Parsing successfull on second try" log print.

Can you show here a failing JSON?

Comment: Log the JSON to the logcat before you try to parse it and track down exact data you're trying to parse before exception - this way you can debug if the data is correct. Probably there is a bug in the backend you're using.

Comment: have you verified your json?
you can try using this [link](http://jsonformat.com/) to verify your json

Comment: The json is fine. It works 3 minutes later (see example code)

Answer (score 0):

Your exception is not full. IllegalStateException have to have some comment here. Something like this.

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2
```

It would be more helpfull if you can see it in such format
So, anyway the error that your Container.class() is not correct type for your containerJson, try to fix it with code like this

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Container>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Container> enums = gson.fromJson(containerJson, collectionType);
```